# Google Maps API V2 no map

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

i´ve been searching and testing a lot of code, but i can´t get map show in my app.
I have my api key writed in manifest and in the layout of my activity for google maps, but
i only can see map screen without any map, only google logo and grill, i can zoom in and out but no any map view and no zoom buttons, what is the reason?
In LogCat log i only see one error:

```
E/MapActivity(1024): Couldn't get connection factory client
W/System.err(1024): IOException processing: 26
W/System.err(1024): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
W/System.err(1024):at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
```

Here ismy code.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.emapps.alarmmap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.emapps.alarmmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.emapps.alarmmap.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.emapps.alarmmap.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.emapps.alarmmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.emapps.alarmmap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyBxdPiMVTg5_XgRAitoQ5XGyFL8sBTS79A" />
        </activity>
        <uses-library 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps_view" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyBxdPiMVTg5_XgRAitoQ5XGyFL8sBTS79A"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**And Activity.java:**

```
package com.emapps.alarmmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MapsView extends MapActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I know that this capture is from API V1,im using APi V2,it is only for reference of my problem.

- http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/4061/5ay7.jpg

I have tried on AVD and Phones with same result.
Sorry for my english and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing deprecated Google Maps Android API v1 with new API v2. Remove all you code and start by following this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Thanks! I will try again with that,hope it works this time hehe ;)

Comment: ihave writed my code again based on the link above,now when i launch my app google maps v2 appears,but there is no map,only blank screen with google logo and zoom buttons,API KEY is in the manifest with neccessary permissions, and declared open GL 2.0 too,layout with fragment code and activity.java same as google says in the link,but no map showing. Google Play Services has been added too like a library to my project,minSDK its 10 ,and im compiling it with SDK 15(4.0.3),i don´t know what to do more to show the map on screen,what i doing wrong?